# getting php array values into a javascript array

Tags: php, jquery

I need to return an array in php and use it in javascript. When I print the returned value it prints empty string. How do I make mistake?

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "sort2.php",    
     success: function(result){      

     alert(result[0]);                                            

    }
});
```

//sort2.php

```
$data[0] = "book";
$data[1] = "pen";
$data[2] = "school";
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: what happens when you `alert(result)`

Comment: it gives an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the JSON data

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "sort2.php",    
     success: function(result){      

     //Parse Json to Array 
     result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
     alert(result) // would output the result array                                      

    }
});
```

Comment: Not necessary; see alex's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `dataType` of your `$.ajax()` request to `json` and have jQuery automatically decode your JSON object from string.

Alternatively, you could add to your PHP `header('Content-Type: application/json')` and jQuery should also automatically decode your JSON string.

Comment: with no dataType set, it should default to `auto`. Is the particular formatting being returned such that it won't auto detect the JSON?

Comment: @GregPettit I believe auto looks at the MIME type to try and guess the format. If the response's MIME is `text/html` (PHP's default MIME type response), it is going to guess wrong.

Comment: I've always explicitly set dataType myself (it makes for better readability, too), but I was curious. Certainly it wouldn't hurt to be explicit!

Comment: I have written as  dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){  
  alert(result[0]);... but doesnt work

Comment: @user1077300 *doesn't work* doesn't help anyone. Did you get an error? What was produced? What does `result` look like?

Comment: I have run it in server and it works. But in mu local it says it doesnt an object. www.dilyurdu.com/test.php works.

Answer (score 1):

In your `sort2.php` file, change the following code:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

to

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

What it does is tell the client browser to treat the response as JSON data and parse accordingly and not as HTML, which is the default.

Also, make sure `sort2.php` file is in the same folder as the html file from where you are making the ajax call.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you also can use the $.post method by jQuery, which would look like this: (so you don't need to change your php script, see here: [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)).

```
$.post(
    'sort2.php', //script you request
    {}, //post-data you want to send
    function(result) {
        alert(result[0]); /*i like more: console.log(result); this way you can see it in firebug e.g.) */
    },
    'json' //data-type you expect
);
```

Comment: when I run this code in server it works. but in my local it gives en error in the alert(result[0]) line as it is null, or doesnt an object. what can be the problem?

Comment: try 'alert(result);' or better with 'console.log(result);' (which will be displayed in firebug->console). And check with firebug what the php script returns in firebug (might be the problem of local php). Php error won't be displayed when using ajax everytime. [link](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v303/cstapetrei/Blog/firebug-1.png)

Comment: alert(result); gives "undefined", when I write console.log it says console "undefined"

Comment: then there is a problem with your php. Need to know what your phpscript returns

Comment: when I run php script, it prints nothing. json_encode doesnt work in my local then.

Comment: it wont print anything, because you call it per ajax. The only way you can see it is in javascript console. Every average browser has such a console. But there're some extensions which are quite useful, for example firebug for firefox (which you can open with pressing f12 after installing). There's a console (which you must activate, but you only have to klick on "activate" and reload the page). In the 2. comment to this answer i posted a link to an image. (thats how it looks like).